# How write the word "plus" after { in reledmac Xfootnote?

Tags: footnotes, reledmac

Here is my problem: I'm writing a latin critical edition with LateX, using reledmac package. I want to indicate that when manuscripts E and V say "pocius audire volo quam scribere", manuscript R says "plus vellem audire quam aliquid scribere", but I've got a problem with the word "plus" which seems to need mathematical environment when used in Xfootnote (no problem when typing "plus" in the main text).

I first wrote

```
quoniam de hoc \edtext{pocius audire volo quam scribere.}
    {\lemma{pocius...scribere \textit{EV}}
    \Afootnote{plus vellem audire quam aliquid scribere \textit{R}}}
```

But when I tried to compile, I got the error "missing number, treated as zero", and "illegal number unit".
I found that the problem was with the word "plus", so I tried this solution:

```
quoniam de hoc \edtext{pocius audire volo quam scribere.}
    {\lemma{pocius...scribere \textit{EV}}
    \Afootnote{$plus$ vellem audire quam aliquid scribere \textit{R}}}
```

Here I can compile the document, but the word "plus" is printed in italics. This is a problem, because in critical apparatus words in italics are considered to be your own addition, which is not the case for my "plus". Does anybody know how to do for "plus" not to be printed in italics?

Comment: You could do with including a complete compilable document that demonstartes this - package interactions can sometimes be an issue for example.  However using maths mode for a workaround `$...$` isn't going to help much.  Have you tried another set of curly brackets around the "plus"?

Comment: I can't replicate it.  I've pasted your text into the bare minimum needed to get reledmac to run and I don't get the same error.

Comment: It looks like a bug in the `\Afootnote` command (see _The TeXbook_, Exercise 27.4).  Where is it defined?  In any case, the problem should go away if you type `\Afootnoe{\relax plus ... }`.

Comment: please provides a MWE, it is a bug that I think have corrected it on the version 2.9.1 of reledmac, now on CTAN. So 1) let me know which version of reledmac you use 2) let me know your full MWE.

Comment: @Maïeul I had to download reledmac to try to duplicate the OP's problem and couldn't - you might have just told me why (I was considering Gustavo's approach but wanted to test it first).

Comment: @ChrisH : the problem is that problem was happened only with certain reledmac configuration. So without a full MWE, we an't be be sur version 2.9.1 have corrected Isabelle's case (but I think it add, and this case should not happened any more). The Gustavo approach is true.

Comment: @Maïeul "the problem...without a full MWE", is true all too often.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is solved with a software update.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved on the newest version of reledmac.